# How can I correctly create a new variable in vvar.h for my new VSDO func?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, system-calls, vdso

I am trying to declare a new variable in `vvar.h` and define it near my new VDSO function. So that I could use this variable in my vdso function.

I have a question about VVar. According to the description in `arch/x86/include/asm/vvar.h`, when I declare here a new variable as `DECLARE_VVAR(0, int, count)`, I should use `DEFINE_VVAR(type, name)` to define this variable somewhere else.

The problem is after I defined this variable somewhere else, like `DEFINE_VVAR(int, count)`, when I am trying to assign an integer value to this variable `count`, it is failed. This is because after kernel version 5.2 `#define DEFINE_VVAR(type, name)` has been changed from `#define DEFINE_VVAR(type, name) type name` to `#define DEFINE_VVAR(type, name) type name[CS_BASES]`. Right now this variable `count` is an integer array instead of type integer. Therefore I can't assign a integer value to it. Do you know how to fix it?

VVAR.h: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.12/source/arch/x86/include/asm/vvar.h#L43

Comment: It's already defined. What are you trying to achieve? It is clearly that you haven't got what VDSO is and how it works from kernel p.o.v. Hint: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.12/source/include/vdso/datapage.h#L59

Comment: my variable is a simple variable ,not clock-source-dependent. i just want to implement a vdso call and a system call.  in system call i will update this variable ,then i can see the update result by vdso call

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you cannot add a variable simply through `DECLARE_VVAR` macro.

The first thing you have to be aware of is that `.vvar` is a page of memory located inside the memory (more specifically, before `.vdso`) and could access by both kernel and userland. You can see this inside the linker script https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/entry/vdso/vdso-layout.lds.S. For now, kernel already has a data structure `struct video to format the data inside this page.

Second, assume you want to add a variable inside the `.vvar` page and access it in your new vdso function, the easiest way is to add it inside the `sturct vdso` structure of include/vdso/datapage.h: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/vdso/datapage.h. After that, you can update them inside the kernel (for example, in schedule) in the same way as other vvar variables.

Second, if you want to own your own vvar page, you have to define your own vvar data structure inside the `datapage.h` and do not forget `DEFINE_VVAR` in `vsyscall.h`: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/include/asm/vdso/vsyscall.h ALso, since the vvar memory layout is compact, you also need to allocate another page through linker script: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/entry/vdso/vdso-layout.lds.S by change `vvar_start = . - 4 * PAGE_SIZE;` into `vvar_start = . - 5 * PAGE_SIZE;`